# Proof of existence and uniqueness of IVP without Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

EDIT: could I use a method like that on page 74 of this book?
http://paguirre.mat.utfsm.cl/edo-2015-2/perko.pdf
It looks like it assumes the Lipshitz constant from a lemma....

I am trying to find a rigorous proof that shows existence and uniqueness of an ode IVP without a Lipschitz condition.

I would prefer a link to a good proof if possible.

I have been looking, but all I can find are the Picard theorem and other theorems that require a Lipschitz constant to show the uniqueness part (but I don't have that in the question I am studying). I have read that the Lipschitz is sufficient but not necessary.

I was looking at the existence theorem for a bit, but I really want something that shows uniqueness as well without the need for the Lipschitz constant.

Here are two variations of my general question...

[image]

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Regarding your edit, yes because $C^1$ implies locally Lipschitz (you should try to prove this as an exercise). The regularity of the solution is actually the hard bit (and the most coolest part of the result), and it follows from the reformulation of the IVP as an integral equation.

Comment: You get $y\in C^1$ as solution of an ODE with continuous right side. If the right side is $C^1$, then from the integral formulation one can easily see that $y\in C^2$.